# How can I get the data from a collection with multiple-level object arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm just started with MongoDB in few days, Here is my collection:

```
{
    PlayerUid:1
    ListData:
    [
        {
            Id:100
            ListInfo:[
                {
                    Uid:1,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:2,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:3,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:4,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Id:101
            ListInfo:[
                {
                    Uid:5,
                    content:"Which I wanted"
                },
                {
                    Uid:6,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:7,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:8,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    PlayerUid:2
    ListData:
    [
        {
            Id:100
            ListInfo:[
                {
                    Uid:9,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:10,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:11,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:12,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Id:101
            ListInfo:[
                {
                    Uid:13,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:14,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:15,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                },
                {
                    Uid:16,
                    content:"Those I don't care"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the data with condition PlayerUid = 1, Id:101 , Uid = 5.

I'v tried

```
findOne({ PlayerUid: 1}, { ListData: { $elemMatch: { Id: 101 } } })
```

and I got

```
{
  ListData: [ { Id: 101, ListInfo: [Array] } ]
}
```

then I'm stuck ,I don't know how to get or filer the data in ListInfo.
What I expected was like

```
{
    Uid:5,
    content:"Which I wanted"
}
or
{
    PlayerUid:1
    ListData:
    [
        {
            Id:100
            ListInfo:
            [
                {
                    Uid:5,
                    content:"Which I wanted"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is that posible?

Ps:This is my fisrt post sorry for something I do wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'd changed store constructor to key-value like

```
{
    '1':
    {
        '100':
        {
            '9':{
                Uid:9,
                content:"Those I don't care"
            },
            '10':{
                Uid:10,
                content:"Those I don't care"
            }
        }
        '200':{
            '11':{
                Uid:11,
                content:"Those I don't care"
            },
            '12':{
                Uid:12,
                content:"That I wanted"
            }
        }
    },
    '2':
    {
        '100':
        {
            '13':{
                Uid:13,
                content:"Those I don't care"
            },
            '14':{
                Uid:14,
                content:"Those I don't care"
            }
        }
        '200':{
            '15':{
                Uid:15,
                content:"Those I don't care"
            },
            '16':{
                Uid:16,
                content:"That I wanted"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and It's gose well.